# What do _._ files mean in nuget packages?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

While looking at the contents of a Nuget package I came across the following file named:

`_._`

Shown by the Image below:

[image]

What does this file mean or do in nuget packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/744#issuecomment-123411563)

> They are placeholder files to denote an empty directory. Empty directories are often not well-supported in ZIPs so a file with that name is placed in there to ensure the directory is created.
>
> This is important because the existence of an "empty" net46 folder
>   means that the package supports .NET Framework 4.6, but does not
>   require any assemblies (DLLs) in order to run on that version of .NET.
>   This is most likely because the implementation of the package is in
>   the GAC.

Answer (score 6):

They are placeholder files to denote an empty directory.
Empty directories are often not well-supported in ZIPs so a file with that name is placed in there to ensure the directory is created.